# How to Append to a file (FTP Python)

Tags: python, ftp

I just wanted to ask how do you **append a file** when using the **FTP library** in python. I understand how to read/upload a file using FTP but how would i append to one. I was looking online and it montioned using a function called '**APPE'** but im not sure how this works. This is what i have so far.

```
ftp= FTP('some ip',a username','password')
ftp.cwd('directory/direct/dir')
ftp.storbinary('STOR atestfile.txt', open ('/home/pi/aFolder/afile1.txt', 'rb'))
ftp.close()
```

I would like to **append the 'atestfile.txt'** file.
Thanks
~Neamus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import ftplib
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('some ip')
    ftp.login ('username','password')
    fin = open ('foo.txt', 'r')
    ftp.storbinary ('APPE foo2.txt', fin, 1)
    ftp.close()
```

Please make sure the file on the server is writable.